# WSO2-IS how to retrieve tenant domain from JWT token?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need a way to put tenant domain info in JWT token (like a claim)?

I've to retrieve it in my java application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe you are talking about the `ID Token` of the `OpenID connect` spec.

Easier way to achieve this is to tick the `Use tenant domain in local subject identifier` option of your Service Provider application's `Local and outbound configurations` section. This will append the tenant domain at the end of the username in the `sub` field of the ID token as below. (Your Java application can process that extract the tenant domain)
`"sub": "admin@carbon.super"`

If you don't like that approach, you might want to write a custom ID token builder extending the [default](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/openidconnect/DefaultIDTokenBuilder.java). Defined in the **identity.xml** file as `<IDTokenBuilder>org.wso2.carbon.identity.openidconnect.DefaultIDTokenBuilder</IDTokenBuilder>`